# aurelia-dialog changed styles on upgrade

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

We tried to upgrade aurelia-dialog from beta.3.0.0 to rc.1.0.3 and found that 2 problems in all our dialog views:

1. The header does not have width 100% as it was before, it only shows header text, looks like "width:-webkit-fit-content" affected this.
2. The dialog body became transparent, so we see underlying elements.

How to we avoid this?

Comment: I would submit this as an issue on the dialog repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since rc.1 they switched their 'ai' prefix to 'ux', so now you have to type `<ux-dialog>` instead of `<ai-dialog>`
This is probably the reason your layout isn't rendering right.
You can see the changelog [here](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog/releases)